# TypeScript: Can't define class inside an IIFE

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I want to define a class inside an IIFE using TypeScript and keeps getting error, `class can be defined either in a module or a file`. Below code does not work.

```
(function(){
    // Error here
    class Person {

    }
})()
```

The reason i need to do this is because i don't want to expose any global variables, not even module. You may wonder why, because i would add them to angular modules in below way

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app').controller('HomeController', HomeController);
    // error here
    class HomeController {
    }
})();
```

Comment: Typescript already wraps the class's contents into a `function()`, so I'm not sure what you want to achieve - just check the generated code at http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/ . Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: I think that it will be possible [with TS 1.6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#16) : "Support for local types and class expressions".

Answer (score 4):

When you create a class, it generates an IIFE for you:

The class:

```
class Example {

}
```

Results in the JavaScript:

```
var Example = (function () {
    function Example() {
    }
    return Example;
})();
```

If you want to keep your classes out of the global scope, you can use modules:

```
module Stack {
    export class Example {

    }

    export class Overflow {

    }
}
```

Only the `Stack` module appears in the global scope.

```
var Stack;
(function (Stack) {
    var Example = (function () {
        function Example() {
        }
        return Example;
    })();
    Stack.Example = Example;
    var Overflow = (function () {
        function Overflow() {
        }
        return Overflow;
    })();
    Stack.Overflow = Overflow;
})(Stack || (Stack = {}));
```

If you want to go a step further, you can use external modules - when you do that, none of your classes or modules is added to the global scope.

Comment: But `Stack` is exposed and khagesh "don't want to expose any global variables".

Comment: I have shown a number of solutions, the last one is zero-global-scope (external modules). The goal of zero-global-scope is admirable, but I like to provide answers that will help other people looking for fewer items in global scope as well as zero items.

Comment: @SteveFenton, as Tarh said, it still exposes Stack as a global variable. And using external modules, means you will have to use require.js for client side. It still does not solve the problem at hand.

Comment: @khagesh - I'm just presenting all of the current options. The decision of which one to use is entirely yours: you can use external modules and leave nothing on the global scope, or you accept one item on the global scope, or you can avoid using classes.

Comment: @SteveFenton, I agree with your point. As of now i have avoided using classes. I don't want to leave any global variables. Because same pattern will be applicable to many other files and they all can't have one global variable each.

Comment: Did you know that you can contribute to the same module across all of your files (i.e. 20 files would still only add to the single global) ?